# Get recently viewed product collection Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, collection, model, recently-viewed

I have tried this but it is not working.
I am getting blank array.
Suggestions please, i am stuck.

I want to display recently viewed product in owl carousel. But getting no products.

```
protected $recentlyViewed;

public function __construct(\Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed ) {
    $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
}

public function execute() {
    $collection = $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection()->load();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($collection->getData());
    exit;
}
```

I also tried this, but still blank array.

```
protected $_viewProductsBlock;

public function __construct(\Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed\Proxy $viewedProductsBlock) {
    $this->_viewProductsBlock         = $viewedProductsBlock;
}
public function execute() {
    $_collection = $this->_viewProductsBlock->getItemsCollection();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_collection->getData());
    echo "</pre>";
    die;
}
```

Comment: Have you check that do you get data into the collection?

Comment: Yes, there are so many in recently viewed, but still i am getting blank array.

Comment: if my answer help you, please mark as solution as well, so it help other into community as well.

Comment: Any solution here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this code :

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block\RecentlyViewed;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $recentlyViewed;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
        parent::__construct( $context, $data );
    }

    public function getMostRecentlyViewed(){
        return $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection()->getData();
    }
}
```

Then you can call this block according to your requirement.

Comment: I also tried this, but not working.

Comment: Kindly confrim this things.
1. You replace the path into above code.
2. Run the magento commands after above changes and then check.

Answer (score 1):

add  cacheable="false" in CMS page block as Mage is tracking visitor id for cached CMS pages which is returning blank.

```
{{block class="CP\Recentproducts\Block\RecentlyViewed" name="recentproduct_recentlyviewed" template="CP_Recentproducts::recentlyviewed.phtml" cacheable="false" }}
```